# How to get splist object when the display name is in a foreign language?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm writing a web service that receives a list name as a parameter and analyzes the list.
To get splist object i'm using the following code (where 'ListName' is the function parameter):

```
SPWeb oWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList oList = oWeb.Lists[ListName];
```

This works great when the list name is in English, but when the list name is in a foreign language i get the exception:

**Server was unable to process request. ---> Value does not fall within the expected range.**

Encoding the ListName parameter didn't help.

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What's the name of the list in foreign language ? Try to pass the GUID of the list. If you Use oWeb.TryGetList instead of Lists you can check if return is null instead of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's localized name?
When you make localized solutions, you can get list by Guid or [by url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlist.aspx):

```
var web = SPContext.Current.Web;
var list = web.GetList(SPUtility.ConcatUrls(web.Url, "Lists\ListName");
```